# Reliability of linear regression to predict future

Tags: statistics, regression

When we have a set of data, where X is the cause, and Y is the effect, we can use linear regression to predict values for Y, based on values of X.

I have learned that you may only safely apply this for values of X that fall into the domain of X for the input data.

Can we also use linear regression to do reliable predictions about values of Y for values X that lie outside of this domain, and if so, what can we say about the reliability of these predictions?

I would love some answers and possibly some interesting sources on this subject.

Comment: In the context of machine learning, the issue you are raising is called "overfitting" (the training data). To avoid overfitting, you may typically want to introduce a regularization term.

Comment: @mathse I don't think this is overfitting. The poster is asking about *extrapolating* a linear model beyond the domain of the data, not how many parameters his model should have to explain the available data.

Comment: @Eupraxis1981 Regularization doesn't determine the number of parameters, but merely their size ... Typically, overfitting arises when the sample available (and used to train regression parameters) is from a particular subspace of the general population ... Isn't that what he's asking for?

Comment: I think popovitsj may want to discuss the concept of consistent estimator and also Gauss-Markov theorem?

Comment: @mathse yes and no. Any sample is a subset of the population, by definition, however, there is a difference between the following two situations: you fit bivariate linear model to data where $X\in [0,10]$ and (1) you want to know its predictive accuracy for another sample *from* $X\in[0,10]$ (2) Its predictive accuracy when the model is used for $X>10$. Regularization will definitely help with (1) but not (2) which is what the poster is asking about.

Comment: @Eupraxis1981 Regularization might certainly help with (2) as well.

Comment: @mathse I don't see how. Without data in that range, how would you penalize its predictions in that domain? On the page you reference, it shows that regularization requires X values within a range. If you don't have data for a certain domain, then you either must assume that the observed trend holds, or do not extrapolate. Numerical shrinkage methods only help in avoid fitting to the noise of the *available data*

Comment: @Eupraxis1981 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting.

Comment: @mathse could you point out the statment in that link that supports using regularization to minimize extrapolation errors? This is different from cross-validation, where you purposefully withold data to test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[XKCD](http://xkcd.com) explains it perfectly in [this](http://xkcd.com/605/) comic, which is

[image: XKCD Weddings & Extrapolation]

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's not advised as the uncertainty of such an extrapolation cannot be quantified (the functional relationship of X on Y could drastically change outside your data). However, if you assume that the observed linear relationship holds outside the range of the data, then you can form a [prediction interval](http://www.stat.duke.edu/~tjl13/s101/slides/unit6lec3H.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

All machine learning approaches, including linear regression, may suffer from overfitting the data. To avoid this, one can include a penalty or regularization term that penalizes "unlikely" parameter values. You may wish to google the term "Lasso" or look here http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/lasso.html

Comment: This does not answer the question about what is the reliability but instead is a suggestion on how to improve the reliability.